# How we can trigger Azure Notification Hub to send push notification to iOS devices from .net web application?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, api, xamarin.forms, azure-notificationhub

We are looking for a process to trigger the Azure Notification hub to send notification to specific registered user from .net application (web application). So far, we can created appropriate profiles and certificates from apple developer portal, registered/configured azure notification hub with iOS certificate and we can able to send Test notification to iOS mobile devices. Now we are looking for a way to trigger the azure notification hub to send the push notification to specific devices.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi , it seems like a trigger in web service , then can send notification to mobile device.

Comment: Hi Junior Jiang, if possible could you please share some related documentation about this process?
Thank you

Comment: Hi Sam. Could you possibly add some more details to what you are trying to do, or what you are hoping Notification Hubs can do for you? Currently, sending a notification would require your code to call the Send API (either using the .NET SDK or through a POST request). So it'd be up to your code to call that API when the trigger event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official documentations.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/push-notifications-android-specific-users-firebase-cloud-messaging

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-ios-apple-apns-notification